# Update Data In MySQL Gives Error

Tags: mysql

```
update table1 
set isDeleted = 1 
where isDeleted = 0 
and mId in (select id from table1 where isDeleted = 1 );
```

Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause

Comment: table1
id mid salary
1  null 10000
2  1 8000
3  1 8000
4  2 6000

update table1 set mid = t2.mid where mId in (select id from table1 as t2 where t2.mid is not null );

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.mId = t2.id
SET t1.isDeleted = 1
WHERE t1.isDeleted = 0
AND t2.isDeleted = 1
```